# How to name a particular curve plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have lines of different colors in a same graph. I want to name each line associated with a particular colour. I want the names displayed not in the graph, but on the right side outside of the graph. Does:

```
line(......,xname="This_Is_The_Name_Associated_With_BlueColourLine")
```

work? I think xname displays names on the lines itself. Please help.Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for a legend?

Comment: try the directlabels package

Comment: Why not use `legend` ?  If you start creating text labels and mini-line segments at a specified location, you're pretty much re-creating a legend.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  ya i think i should use legend. Can you give me a usage example. I have seen example at http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/ . But i couldn't understand the terms in it. Can you help by giving a small example please

Comment: `legend` is base graphics, so it won't play nice with ggplot2 (e.g. placement after resizing, ggsave, etc)

Comment: @baptiste -- I'm not a regular user of `ggplot2` , so can you suggest the aesthetic which is analogous to `legend` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft there isn't one; aesthetics are a different beast altogether. You'd be looking for a `geom_legend()` in ggplot2 parlance, or more exactly an `annotation_legend()` (which doesn't exist, I'm afraid). Now that I read the question more carefully, though, it appears that the OP simply wants the default kind of legend, outside the graph, that ggplot2 displays automatically when the data was mapped with `aes()`. A minimal reproducible example would  solve this in seconds ([or, alternatively](http://xkcd.com/1022/), reading an intro manual to ggplot2).